# How to create web pages dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

In social network sites multiple users can open their profile details at a time.

How to implement this facility using Asp.net. I hope for this I need to create profile web page dynamically.

How to create dynamically web pages for users.

Comment: I don't understand what your asking. The whole PURPOSE of asp.net is creating dynamically generated web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Very broadly speaking, you will create several "page templates" with certain elements that will be changed dynamically based on the required content.

You might want to look at the tutorial at http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/getting-started which can give you some idea of how these things are done. You can than come back with more specific questions.